# Unable to load DLL 'tensorflow' ML.Net & .Net Framework 4.6.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ml.net

I have a .Net Framework "4.6.2" web application and I have created ml model and want to use it in the web app, but when I try to load the model like this:

```
ITransformer mlModel = mlContext.Model.Load(_modelPath, out var modelInputSchema);
```

I get the following error:

> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'tensorflow': The specified
> module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Updates:
when I create core console app and use the same ml model it works correctly but when I use .Net Framework "4.6.2" web application it doesn`t work

Comment: There's no .NET Framework 6.2. .NET Framework goes only up to 4.8. Did you mean 4.6.2 perhaps?

Comment: Looks like you are using Entity (mlContext.Model) and there is a mapping file that is used to link the database tables to the c# classes.   The Load() method is trying to connect to database and is using  tensorflow to make the connection.  Do you know where the dll is located when you run locally?

Comment: Have you tried installing the SciSharp.Tensorflow.Redist package?

Comment: @Jon yes I`ve installed it & still not working

Comment: @jdweng which dll that you mean ?

Comment: Tensorflow.  the error is due to the _modelpath not being found.  So I think the model and the Tensorflow have some incompatibility issues.

Comment: @jdweng the model works well with core app but not with .net 4.6.2 unfortunately and I can`t figure out why

Comment: Can you update to Net 4.7.2 or newer?  Net 4.7.2 can use same source and deploy to either  Core or Net.  What version Net are you using?  Usually Core Breaks, not Net.

Comment: @jdweng I`ve tried to  use 4.7.2 and the same error appears unfortunately

Comment: Did you do a clean build?  Changing version of Net does not automatically update the intermediate obj files.